# Is there a way to make regions in term modes respect line wrapping?

Tags: emacs, terminal-emulator

When using a `term` mode derivative (like `ansi-term` or `multi-term`), I often want to select a region and copy it someplace else. If that region includes a line which wraps at the edge of the terminal window, pasting that region in another buffer always inserts a hard newline at the place where `term` wrapped the line. This means I often have to go back and clean up pasted text. Is there a way to avoid doing this? I tried both `term-line-mode` and `term-char-mode`; both do the same thing.

I do not want to write a yank hook which strips out all newlines, since I want to preserve existing hard newlines in the original content.

Comment: Please forgive me for not having enough background with term type mode buffers, but from my inexperienced point of view the first thing I wonder is whether there is any difference that can be seen between a new line with a command prompt and a word-wrapped line -- perhaps being the cursor prompt -- e.g., something $ or the like?  If so, then the solution would be to fix the region such that hard returns that do not result in a prompt, should be treated as word-wrapped and thus the hard return deleted and replaced with a space.  Just thinking out loud, so please excuse me if I'm off base . . .

Comment: Interesting idea, but I don't think it works. Consider a term buffer 50 characters wide running a shell. You execute `cat myfile.txt`, where `myfile.txt` contains plain text hard-wrapped at 80 characters. The output won't have any obvious wrapping markers like shell prompt characters, it'll just wrap twice (once at the 50-char boundary, and once at the 80-char boundary). (And copying text from that output will preserve the soft 50-char newline as a hard newline.)

I'm almost tempted to call this a bug in `term.el`, but that code is not the easiest to understand and amend without breaking it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me:

```
(setq term-suppress-hard-newline t)
```

Comment: Interesting! I had that set to nil, with a comment that it made GNU screen work better. Double-checked: yes, screen and `term-suppress-hard-newline` set to t don't get along. However, I switched to tmux a while ago, and tmux works well with with t. Thank you.

Comment: Where has this been all my life